# Proof Check of Irreducibility of $x^2 +1$ in a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am studying for my qualifying exams and I just want to verify that I have done this problem correctly.

First, let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field with the property,
$$ a^2 + b^2 = 0 \implies a = 0 \textrm{ and } b = 0.$$

Show that $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}\lbrack x \rbrack.$

So first, I basically justified that $\mathbb{F}\lbrack x \rbrack$ was a unique factorization domain because every field is a principal ideal domain, thus a unique factorization domain, which implies $\mathbb{F}\lbrack x \rbrack$ is as well. Now, assume to get a contradiction that $x^2 + 1$ is reducible. This implies there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $$x^2 + 1 = (x+a)(x+b) = x^2+(a+b)x+ab.$$ The linear part of this equation implies $a = -b$, so the equation becomes,
$$ x^2+(a+b)x + ab = x^2 -a^2.$$
This further implies that $a^2 = -1$. Now if we let $b = 1$ we see $a^2 + b^2 = -1+1 = 0$ which violates our field axiom. Thus no such $a$ exists and $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible.

I'm not quite sure that this is correct, and I would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: It is correct but I think the foreword about UFD's is useless. You can say directly that a quadratic polynomial is reducible over F iff it has a root in F.

Comment: I think you used $b$ for more than one quantity.  Maybe let $c=1$

Comment: Yes, to avoid conflict of notation, may be you should better write $x^2+1=(x+a)(x+c)=\dots,$ then $a^2=-1,$ and then let $b=1.$ (Since the notations $a,b$ are used in the definition of the property of your field.)

Comment: great. thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I would write the conclusion as: "$a^2+1^2=-1+1=0 \Longrightarrow 1=0$" which contradicts the field property of $\mathbb{F}."$ Reason: it avoids a double mention of b and it gets rid of a, so nobody has to think about whether $a=-1=0$ is possible or not.

Comment: If reducible it has a linear factor so it has a root $\,r\in\Bbb F\,$ so $\,r^2+1^2=0\,$ so $\ldots$